# Access VBA - Delete All .accdb Except For Open Copy In Folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to write an OnOpen() / OnClose() event that will delete *.accdb files from a user's downloads folder. I've got the snippet below that works great, unless a copy is physically open in the drive:

```
Public Function DeleteLocalDBs()
strUserName = Environ("UserName")
strPath = "C:\documents and settings\" & strUserName & "\Downloads\"
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill strPath & "*.accdb"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

If there's a database copy open, nothing happens.

I've looked through here and google, but haven't found any other solutions. If any of you have ideas/suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Update: I'm not trying to delete the open database. I'm trying to delete other .accdb's that might exist in the folder, which would be previous versions.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to delete it while it's open. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hey there. No, I'm not trying to delete the open one. I'm trying to delete others that might exist in the folder, which aren't open.

Comment: Then I am unsure what you are asking. You say that the code you have works already.

Comment: The code I'm having works if I run it separately, apart from an open database in the folder. If there's an open database in the folder, it does not run.

Comment: Start by removing `On Error Resume Next` and report any possible errors. It's hardly sensible to debug code while suppressing all errors. Also, please clarify what you mean with _unless a copy is physically open in the drive_

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I get a runtime error (70): Permission denied. The reason I get that error is because the database is currently open in the same directory. However, if I execute [the following](https://codepaste.net/t3tqfs) through a .bat file, it will delete the other non-open files successfully. By "copy physically open", I mean the user has that database open on their computer.

Comment: @Parfait - We're using Google Drive as a central place to store databases. Each time a user in my team downloads one of them, it will add a sequential number to the end of the name string instead of overwriting the existing one. For instance, the first time I download Database A, the file name is "Database A". The next time I download it, it is "Database A(1)", and so on. I need to find out a way to delete all that exist in the folder so they don't have multiple older versions.

Comment: @Steve Wolfe, `C:\documents and settings` is a link, not a path. Try with `Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\"` for the current user or `"C:\Users\" & strUserName & "\Downloads\"` for a targeted user.

Comment: @Parfait, TS does not use any internet folders to run MS Access. Seems like you misunderstood and/or didn't understand the previous explanation provided by TS.

Comment: @Rene, you're correct. Only using Google Drive as the storage for the databases. Users download them to their local computer to run.

Comment: @Parfait, We make changes to our dev copies of databases, almost on a daily basis. With the previous process, they were able to execute a [batch file](https://codepaste.net/t3tqfs). Since we're being forced to leave our current shared network drive and move to Google Drive, I've got to figure out a way to get a database to each user, while also keeping the number of databases that they have on their computer to a minimum.

Comment: @Parfait, I'm hosting the Google Folder containing all the productionalized databases via a Google Site. So, they would be using the Web Browser.

Comment: Note to anyone else coming in the future, I was able to resolve this issue with the [following VBA](https://codepaste.net/uhnjm3). Thanks to all for your responses!

Comment: @SteveWolfe ... you can answer your own question!

Comment: @Parfait, did I say something wrong?

Comment: No you are pointing to VBA code and if it is yours, you can answer your own question below.